# Where to find up-to-date video compatibility reference?

Tags: video, webvideos

I am developing a video streaming website and trying to decide on what the best video containers and codecs would be for its use. For this, I need to know what the compatibility of each OS and browser is with each container and codec. Where can I find an up-to-date reference that contains a table summary of this information and is kept up to date?

An example of things I want to know: Per OS, on which browsers are the H.264, H.265, VP9, and AV1 codecs supported (and not supported)? The same question for audio codecs like AAC, Opus, etc.